# jquery on() for every future .abc element and then off() for particular .abc element. how to do that?

Tags: jquery, events, selector

Supposedly my explanation was too complicated so I'll try to symplify what I want:

**EDITED:**

I just try to understand how exactly **on()** works.
Why undermentioned off() **do unbind** *'mouseover mouseout'* events for second LI:

```
$('.li').on('mouseover mouseout',changeBorder);
$('.li:nth-child(2)').off('mouseover mouseout',changeBorder);
```

while undermentioned off() **does not unbind** *'mouseover mouseout'* events for second LI??

```
$('#container').on('mouseover mouseout', '.li',changeBorder);
$('.li:nth-child(2)').off('mouseover mouseout',changeBorder);
```

I want to use first method because I intend to add another LI dynamically in the future, so second method will not bind events for future LIs -just for existing. I can of course bind event for every new dynamically appended LI while I create and append that, but I'm looking for some more elegant way to do that :) So according to the example below, I want the second LI not to react on mouseover, but it reacts as you can see even though I **off()** 'ed it.

```js
$('#container').on('mouseover mouseout', '.li',changeBorder);
$('.li:nth-child(2)').off('mouseover mouseout',changeBorder);

//$('.li').on('mouseover mouseout',changeBorder);
//$('.li:nth-child(2)').off('mouseover mouseout',changeBorder);

function changeBorder(event){
  if(event.type==='mouseover'){
     $(event.target).css('border','dotted 2px #33aaff');
   } else {
    $(event.target).css('border','none');
   }
}
```

```css
.li {
  width:200px;
  list-style-type:none;
  background-color:#efefef;
  padding:6px;
  margin:3px;
  border-radius:3px;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#aaa;
  font-size:20px;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="container">
  <li class="li" contenteditable>sample A</li>
  <li class="li" contenteditable>sample B</li>
  <li class="li" contenteditable>sample C</li>
  <li class="li" contenteditable>sample D</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what's wrong with `$(this).off()`? You haven't explained what problem is with the code shown

Comment: I want $(this).off() to STOP trigerring changeBorder() function, binded with on() in the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly than this might work for you ... and it's a lot less complicated than your code. There is no need for repeatedly binding/unbinding event handlers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.everyFutureItem', function(e){
  // ad border only if elmt is not the activeElement 
  if (e.target != document.activeElement) {
    $(e.target).css('border','dotted 2px #33aaff');
  }
});

$(document).on('mouseleave click', '.everyFutureItem', function(e){ 
  $(e.target).css('border','none');
});
```

```css
.everyFutureItem {
  width:200px;
  list-style-type:none;
  background-color:#efefef;
  padding:6px;
  margin:3px;
  border-radius:3px;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#aaa;
  font-size:20px;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="container">
  <li class="everyFutureItem" contenteditable>sample A</li>
  <li class="everyFutureItem" contenteditable>sample B</li>
  <li class="everyFutureItem" contenteditable>sample C</li>
  <li class="everyFutureItem" contenteditable>sample D</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

OP's explanation of desired behavior is not clear, in order to expedite matters here's an outline of what I interpreted:

1. User points mouse to the second `<li>` **[mouseover]**
2. The handler (i.e. `changeBorder()`) is invoked a border is made on second `<li>`
3. User clicks the mouse on second `<li>` **[focus]**
4. User moves mouse out of the second `<li>` **[mouseout]**
5. The border on the second `<li>` is still there because the `mouseout` and `mouseover` events were unbound from second `<li>` before step 4 happened.
6. When returning mouse to second `<li>` there are no longer any `mouseout` or `mouseover` events being triggered.
7. Upon moving out of the second `<li>`, and clicking outside of the second `<li>` a `blur` event occurred.
8. The second `<li>` is rebound to the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.

In the [jQuery API Documentation - `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Adding or removing event handlers on the current element won't take effect until the next time the event is handled.

Consider the sequence of events and knowing that adding/removing delegated events don't apply until the ***next*** time the event is handled. So in a scenario where:

1. User points mouse to the second `<li>` **[mouseover]**
2. The handler (i.e. `changeBorder()`) is invoked a border is made on second `<li>`
3. User clicks the mouse on second `<li>` **[focus]**
4. User moves mouse out of the second `<li>` **[mouseout]**
5. Second `<li>` borders are gone.
6. The handler is unbound, ***but*** it doesn't look like it worked because the border is still being made as if `changeBorder()` still functions which implies that the second `<li>` is still bound to mouseover and mouseout events.
7. In order to stop this behavior, you have to trigger another `focus` event on the second `<li>`.**[focus]**.

```js
/* Using the direct selector to the <li> */
$('.edit').on({
  /* Mapping events */
  mouseover: activate,
  mouseout: activate,
  focus: function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
    $(this).off('mouseover mouseout', activate);
  },
  blur: function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
    $(this).on('mouseover mouseout', activate);
  }

});

/* Checks to see if event target has class .off... */
/* ...and removes .off and adds .on class... */
/* ...otherwise remove .on and add .off class */
function activate(e) {
  console.log(e.type);
  var tgt = $(e.target);
  tgt.hasClass('off') ? tgt.addClass('on').removeClass('off') : tgt.addClass('off').removeClass('on');
}
```

```css
.edit {
  width: 200px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 20px;
  outline: none;
}
/* Two state classes */

.on {
  border: 2px dotted #33aaff;
}
.off {
  border: 0 none transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li class="edit off" contenteditable>sample A</li>
  <li class="edit off" contenteditable>sample B</li>
  <li class="edit off" contenteditable>sample C</li>
  <li class="edit off" contenteditable>sample D</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your interpretation is correct but example is still not what I want to achieve. https://devrafalko.github.io/regex-tutorial/ here is my working code, try mouseover, focus and blur 'hello hello' boxes and look how mouseover and mouseout events are unbinded when the box is focused. I did it in a bit different way: I added property isFocused for box, onfocus I set to true, onblur set to false, in mouseover function I check if isFocused is true, if so - return (do nothing); It works ok but I still do not understand why on() works :)